# Spring-boot: Configure FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean in web application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to use Freemarker for e-mail templating in a web application.

I have declared a FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean as follow:

```
@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean(EmailTemplateService templateService) {
    FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean configurationFactoryBean = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean();
    configurationFactoryBean.setPreTemplateLoaders(templateService);
    return configurationFactoryBean;
}
```

When running my JUnit everything is working well, but when running in my webapp my bean is "overriden" by the spring boot FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration.

I have tried to:

1. remove the spring-boot-starter-freemarker from my gradle file
2. @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {FreeMarkerAutoConfigurationk.class})
3. spring.freemarker.enabled=false

But without success. Any idea?

Thanks guys.

Comment: How have you identified that Spring Boot is overriding your `FreemarkerConfigurationFactoryBean`? Spring Boot's auto-configuration of it is annotated with `ConditionalOnMissingBean` so it should switch off if you've provided your own

Comment: Actually it does not ovveride my `FreemarkerConfigurationFactoryBean` but the `freemarker.template.Configuration` injected in my class is the one configured by Spring boot and not the one confiured through my `FreemarkerConfigurationFactoryBean`.

Answer (score 0):

As your application is a Web application, it's Spring Boot's `FreeMarkerWebConfiguration` that you're interested in. It doesn't use a `FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean` but a `FreeMarkerConfigurer`. You should create a `FreeMarkerConfigurer` bean and configure it as required. For example:

```java
@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer(EmailTemplateService templateService) {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    configurer.setPreTemplateLoaders(templateService);
    return configurer;
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks it's working. Now why @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {FreeMarkerAutoConfigurationk.class}) is not working ?

Comment: I don't know. It's really a separate question. Perhaps you have a second `EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation without the exclusion?

Comment: @IndustrialProgrammer, because it is package protected!